# Using openZepplin, how do I use the safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, "")?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, openzeppelin

Kindly bare with me as I am new to Solidity and the Web.30 space.

The intention of my DApp is to be able to delay/schedule the transfers of your NFT's from your own account to someone else's.

The idea is that a user should be able to find **most** of his NFT details via the opensea platform and their MetaMask wallet...

Find below my simple solidity code in the Remix IDE:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract CryptoGift is ERC721 {
    address public owner;
    uint256 private birtday = block.timestamp +30; 

     constructor()  ERC721("Crypto Gift", "CGT") public {
        owner = msg.sender;       
    }

    function GiftAFriend (address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public virtual {

       require( block.timestamp >= birtday, "Its NOT your birthday yet!" );
       safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, ""); 
    }

}
```

The settings I used in my Remix IDE are:

ENVIRONMENT: **Web3 Provider**

I was able to successfully Deploy to the **Rinkeby Test Network**
this means I am also able to see all the interfaces in Remix as illustrated below

[image: The interface in Remix]

When running my **GiftAFriend** function, I used the details found in my NFT contract/address from my https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0x1a2795bbdbc6b6fc1d777b47b9c1516a642ca7f7/1
and for the **to**, I used one of my fictitious MetaMask addresses.

For the **tokenId**, I used the **tokenId** at the end of my opensea address https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0x1a2795bbdbc6b6fc1d777b47b9c1516a642ca7f7/1

When I click the **transact** for my **GiftAFriend** function I am met with the following error message in Remix:
[image: error message in Remix]

Kindly tell me where & What I am doing wrong?

Comment: the links don't work

Comment: @v1bio Sorry the links to the testnets.opensea.io are now working.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you're address doesn't have any activity.

I'm not sure if this is only an excerpt from you code but ERC721 require all of these imports (or directly adding these into your contract):

```
import "../../utils/Context.sol";
import "./IERC721.sol";
import "./IERC721Metadata.sol";
import "./IERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "./IERC721Receiver.sol";
import "../../introspection/ERC165.sol";
import "../../math/SafeMath.sol";
import "../../utils/Address.sol";
import "../../utils/EnumerableSet.sol";
import "../../utils/EnumerableMap.sol";
import "../../utils/Strings.sol";
```

Furthermore, the *GiftAFriend* function listed on openZepplin changes the existing index on the SAME contract from *from* to *to*, it cannot inheritably manipulate the transfer for any external collection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I corrected the links to my testnets.opensea.io links, so kindly feel free to try again.

Notice the import at the beginning of my contract (import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin....), that import adds/includes an openZepplin library that adds all the required/necessary imports.

The GiftAFriend function is not part of the openZepplin library, but my own intended to transfer the NFT token from the owner account to an account of their choosing but with a delay of 30 seconds.